# OS X: Run script at Login screen with FileVault on

Tags: macos, launchd, osx-yosemite, filevault, launchctl

How to run a script at Login screen (**BEFORE** user types password to log in)?

I have tried `launchctl` and place the script under both:

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/
/Library/LaunchAgents/
```

Still the script is executed **AFTER** log in.

Am I missing something?

*Edit:*

- I tried `/Library/StartupItems` also didn't work.
  Is the LaunchDaemons supposed to launch **after** Login or **before**. Have anyone successfully make it run **before** Login?
- I'm running on Yosemite.

Comment: Do you mean *whenever* the login screen is shown, or just once after booting your Mac?

Comment: Either of them is ok, just before the user log in. Calling the script _once_, or _whenever_ (multiple times) are both fine.

Comment: are you talking about login after boot? or do you mean the password right afterstarting the computer? As the later is requesting the password to unlock your filevaulted harddrive nothing on that harddrive can be executed before.

Comment: As in my computer, I only have to enter 1 password at login screen. (After pressing power button -> Apple logo -> Login screen -> Enter password -> Load to desktop)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your crontab:

```
@reboot /path/to/file.sh
```

The script will be run once on boot before login.

Comment: Still execute after logging in.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many the ways, I realize that **FileVault** might cause this behavior. Because FileVault requires password in order to decrypt the data, we cannot do anything before entering the password.

This is a conjecture, if someone has any information about this, please feel free to confirm.

If anyone has a work around, please feel free to help.